# How can 2 webcomponents communicate using CustomEvents

Tags: javascript

I have 2 web components, not using any library or framework, just vanilla JS.

```
<app-list />
```

Renders a list of items fetched from the server

```
<app-form />
```

Once the user submits the form, the data is pushed to the server and once a response comes back, the form should dispatch an event to let the app-list know it should fetch it's data again and re-render it.

As I understand https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events the CustomEvent should specify a composed: true property for the event reach outside of it's shadowRoot.

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <ul></ul>`;

class AppList extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["userid"];
  }

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this._list = [];
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[name] = newValue;
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    fetch(`/service/${this.userid}/lists/`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
        console.log(response);
      })
      .then(json => {
        this._list = json.user_lists;
        this.render();
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    let list = this._shadowRoot.querySelector("ul");
    list.innerHTML = "";

    this._list.forEach((item, indx) => {
      let liElm = document.createElement("li");
      liElm.innerHTML = `<div data-id="${item.id}">${item.name}</div>`;
      list.appendChild(liElm);
    });

    console.log("render");
  }
}

export default AppList;
```

AppForm

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<form>
    <label>Name of List</label>
    <input type="text" name="list_name" value="">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  `;

class AppForm extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["name", "userid"];
  }

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  attributeChangeCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
      this[name] = newValue;
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    let userId = this.getAttribute("userid");

    this._shadowRoot.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      let name = e.target["list_name"].value.trim();
      fetch(`/service/${userId}/lists/`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          list_name: name
        })
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          // TODO: Notify the AppList about the change
        });
    });
  }

  render() {}
}

export default AppForm;
```

I tried adding the CustomEvent inside the connectedCallback of the AppForm, but the AppList doesn't get the event.

Dispatch from AppForm

```
this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent("field-changed", {
              detail: { name: name },
              composed: true
            })
          );
```

Listener inside the constructor of the AppList

```
this.addEventListener("field-changed", e => console.log(e));
```

But there is no event triggered inside the AppList once the AppForm dispatches it's event.

**Update**

I managed to get it working by using the parent node to dispatch and listen for the event.

https://github.com/kristiannissen/refactored-engine/blob/dcde6d0e0b325372ef75644c2a3bbbbb9569b7c6/src/webcomponents/AppForm.js#L48

https://github.com/kristiannissen/refactored-engine/blob/dcde6d0e0b325372ef75644c2a3bbbbb9569b7c6/src/webcomponents/AppList.js#L34

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code

Comment: what happens if you just dispatch the event, without doing the fetch?

Comment: Nothing, the addeventlistener is never triggered

Comment: Looking at the link about the shadow DOM: "When we dispatch custom events, we need to set both bubbles and composed properties to true for it to bubble up and out of the component." so it might work the old way if you also set bubbles

Comment: "the old way" what do you mean? - Bieber quote (I think...)

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to store the parent node. You can access the `parentElement` for the `AppList` and add the listener to that:

```js
const form_template = document.createElement("template");
form_template.innerHTML = `<form>
    <label>Name of List</label>
    <input type="text" name="list_name" value="">
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  `;

class AppForm extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["name", "userid"];
    }

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(form_template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    attributeChangeCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            this[name] = newValue;
        }
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        let userId = this.getAttribute("userid");

        this._shadowRoot.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent("field-changed", {
                    detail: { name: name },
                    composed: true,
                    bubbles: true
                })
            );
        });
    }

    render() {}
}

const list_template = document.createElement("template");
list_template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <ul></ul>`;

class AppList extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ["userid"];
    }

    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this._list = [];
        this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
        this._shadowRoot.appendChild(list_template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            this[name] = newValue;
        }
    }

    connectedCallback()
    {
        this.parentElement.addEventListener("field-changed", e =>
                              {
                                  console.log(e);
                              });
    }

    render() {}
}

customElements.define('app-list', AppList);
customElements.define('app-form', AppForm);
```

```html
<app-list></app-list>
<app-form></app-form>
```